# sysbench connect error - MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, dbconnection, sysbench

This sysbench test fails even though my other mysql 8 clients connect just fine from this same bash session to MySQL 8. I have checked the following:

sestatus : is disabled
permissions is fine on /mnt/optane2, the sock file is there. 
made sure I compiled sysbench with the libs and includes from mysql8
No issues with other mysql 8 client tools

Using the latest sysbench 1.0.14

Is there other PATH'ing that is needed.

My PATH variable looks like this:

```
PATH=/home/mysql8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin


# sysbench --tables=8 --table-size=50000000 --mysql-db=dbtest --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=zzz --db-driver=mysql --db-debug=on  --mysql-socket=/mnt/optane2/my.sock /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_write.lua prepare
sysbench 1.0.14 (using bundled LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2)
```

```
FATAL: unable to connect to MySQL server on socket '/mnt/optane2/my.sock', aborting...
FATAL: error 1049: Unknown database 'dbtest'
FATAL: `sysbench.cmdline.call_command' function failed: ./src/lua/oltp_common.lua:98: connection creation failed
```

Comment: I am going to answer my own question here, you should just "create database dbtest;" first  with the mysql client and that should be it. It works otherwise.

I did compile my sysbench as alexey says with the libraries from the mysql8 installation, but haven't rolled things back to see if that matters. I am good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question here, you should just "create database dbtest;" first  with the mysql client and that should be it. It works otherwise, I was in a confusion loop, thinking I was missing something when I was not, the second error was actually the first problem, you were missing the db itself.

I did compile my sysbench as alexey says with the libraries from the mysql8 installation, but haven't rolled things back to see if that matters. I am good to go now.